What is the probability that White will play O-O or O-O-O after 1.e4 and 1.d4?
White plays O-O 80% of the time and O-O-O 9.6% of the time. I'm looking for the same statistics but after 1.e4 and after 1.d4. I'm pretty sure that O-O-O is rarer after 1.d4 than after 1.e4. But how much rarer? I want to see the numbers.

Are you interested in stats from online chess games, official games (i.e. games in the Mega Database) or both?

@double-beep: Any of the two would do, as I don't care too much about accuracy. But I would prefer games by players below 1600 Elo to be excluded.

Stats from Mega Database 2023
Of the 10,034,661 total games in the version of Mega Database 2023 I use, 7,084,704 are between players with more than 1600 Elo. Of these:

3,388,825 begin with e4.

0-0 was played by White in 2,511,122 of these (74.1%).
0-0-0 was played by White in 560,528 of these (16.5%).


2,365,980 begin with d4.

0-0 was played by White in 1,880,115 of these (79.5%).
0-0-0 was played by White in 203,806 of these (8.6%).



For reference, 0-0 was played by White in 5,514,441 games (77.8% of the time), and 0-0-0 in 821,270 games (11.6% of the time).

I used CQLi to search the Mega Database, specifically the find move from K o-o and find move from K o-o-o filters.
